# Is there a regulate expression in Regex.Slit() which splits text into sentences and avoid duplicate sentences in the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

here is the simple code:

```
string input = "First sentence. Second sentence. Third Sentence";

    string[] sentences = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[.])\s+");
```

How can I put some regular expression which avoids sentence duplications ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you're trying to do is not possible. You need to manually filter out duplicates after splitting. You could do this by adding the following Line (based on Jeff Atwood's answer)

```
sentences = sentences.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: is there a solution in Regex Split to put each sentence in new line of a textbox? and after easily can remove the duplicates in that case...